# Given a hash of arrays, how to create an array of hashes with each possible combo

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Given a hash with values containing arrays of unequal lengths,

```
{a: [1, 2, 3], b: [1, 2], c: [1]}
```

is it possible to create an array of hashes containing the same keys, of all permutations of single values like the following without resorting to nesting multiple loops?

```
[
  {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1},
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 1},
  {a: 2, b: 1, c: 1},
  {a: 2, b: 2, c: 1},
  {a: 3, b: 2, c: 1},
  {a: 3, b: 2, c: 1}
]
```

We accomplish this using nested `each` loops for each key, but this looks nasty at a large scale. Actual data contain many more keys.

Comment: First question: What have you tried? Hint: [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) and [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-zip).

Comment: @tadman  zip's no good. Zipping the value of each key with the following key produces nils if the arrays are different sizes. This gives me the values I want: `hsh[:a].product(hsh[:b]).product(hsh[:c]).map(&:flatten)`, now I just need to figure out how to do it without manually getting the product and flattening for each key, and the apply each value to its proper key in the new array of hashes

Comment: Are you talking about permutations or combinations? Or do you not even know what they mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
keys = hash.keys
hash.values.inject(:product).map do |p|
  Hash[keys.zip(p.flatten)]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h = { a:[1,2,3], b:[1,2], c: [1] }

first, *rest = h.map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }
  #=> [[[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:a, 3]], [[:b, 1], [:b, 2]], [[:c, 1]]]
first.product(*rest).map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>1}, {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1}, {:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>1},
  #    {:a=>2, :b=>2, :c=>1}, {:a=>3, :b=>1, :c=>1}, {:a=>3, :b=>2, :c=>1}]
```

Note the intermediate calculation in the second step:

```
first.product(*rest)
  #=> [[[:a, 1], [:b, 1], [:c, 1]],
  #    [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 1]],
  #    [[:a, 2], [:b, 1], [:c, 1]],
  #    [[:a, 2], [:b, 2], [:c, 1]],
  #    [[:a, 3], [:b, 1], [:c, 1]],
  #    [[:a, 3], [:b, 2], [:c, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. Personally, I like @Marcin Kołodziej solution for compactness and effectiveness, however, it may look a little cryptic for newbies.

The other way to solve it is to manually iterate over the hash and build an array:

```
hash = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [1, 2], c: [1] }
out = []

hash.each do |key, values|
  if out.empty?
    out = values.map { |v| { key => v } }
  else
    new_out = []
    out.each do |o|
      new_out += values.map { |v| o.merge(key => v) }
    end
    out = new_out
  end
end

out

# [{:a=>1, :b=>1, :c=>1}, {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>1}, {:a=>2, :b=>1, :c=>1}, {:a=>2, :b=>2, :c=>1}, {:a=>3, :b=>1, :c=>1}, {:a=>3, :b=>2, :c=>1}]
```

Comment: I'm no newbie, just facing a mass of tangled legacy spaghetti code